# Transforming a sequence of tags using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, foreach

I'm kind of new to using [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Stylesheet_Language). I'm trying to convert an XML file into another XML file with a different structure using XSL. The **input** section of the XML goes like this:

```
<tag>
    <Keyword>Event: Some Text</Keyword>
    <Keyword>Group: Some Text</Keyword>
    <Keyword>Other: Some Text</Keyword>
</tag>
```

I would like the desired **output** to be:

```
<tag>
    <event> Some Text </event>
    <group> Some Text </group>
    <other> Some Text </other>
</tag>
```

My **current XSL** file:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tag">
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(Keyword, 'Event: ')">
        <event>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Keyword, 'Event: ')"/>
        </event>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(Keyword, 'Group: ')">
        <group>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Keyword, 'Group: ')"/>
        </group>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(Keyword, 'Other: ')">
        <other>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(Keyword, 'Other: ')"/>
        </other>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The **current output** only shows the event node and does not display the remaining nodes:

```
<tag>
    <event> Some Text </event>
</tag>
```

I tried switching the 'group' section with the 'event' section in the XSL, however all the child nodes are not displayed probably due to the ordering of the keyword nodes in the input XML. So how can I read **all** the keyword nodes and convert them to the respective new nodes for display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one `tag` element.  You want to iterate over all of it's **children**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="tag/*">

    <xsl:if test="starts-with(., 'Event: ')">
        <event>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Event: ')"/>
        </event>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(., 'Group: ')">
        <group>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Group: ')"/>
        </group>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="starts-with(., 'Other: ')">
        <other>
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(., 'Other: ')"/>
        </other>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**EDIT**: added another solution (using @Pierre's original solution).
***Note*** the value of the xsl:element name attribute is wrapped in `{}` so that it is evaluated as an [Attribute Value Template](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N1575.html), rather than as the literal string:

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Keyword"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Keyword">
<xsl:element name="{normalize-space(substring-before(.,':'))}">
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(.,':'))"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You should look at @Pierre's solution and consider trying to do more template matches than for-each statements in your XSLT. It is kind of a different way of doing things(declarative vs. procedural) that is sometimes hard to grasp at first, but it will make development and maintenance a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

@Pierre: I understand initial question and your solution correctly ;)
Your way for XML elements construction IMHO bit of *hackly*. XSLT have special set for dynamic construction of xml elements. So your **template match="Keyword"** can look like this

```
<xsl:template match="Keyword">
  <xsl:variable name="tag" select="normalize-space(substring-before(.,':'))"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$tag}">
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(.,':'))"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

So you have option to easily add attributes to output XML elements if you need, and won't bother with disable-output-escaping etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. You don't have to create all those **if** statements by using **xsl:element**

```
<xsl:template match="tag">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Keyword"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Keyword">
 <xsl:variable name="tag" select="normalize-space(substring-before(.,':'))"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',$tag,'&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(.,':'))"/>
 <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',$tag,'&gt;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: +1 Much more clean.  I was going to add something like that to my answer, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Ah... You may be right. I changed xsl:element to xsl:value-of with @disable-output-escaping='yes'.

Comment: Why you didnt use xsl:element and xsl:attribute for dynamic construction of elements on runtime ? 
Its much better for element construction, but, probably, in this case simple concatenation will work either

Comment: Alexey, here we need to generate the name of the element, not one of its attribute.

Comment: I liked the original code better. All you needed to do was wrap the expression in `{}`, so that the expression was evaluated as an Attribute Value Template.  Disable output escaping in order to jam angle brackets in the output is an evil hack that should not be used.

Comment: @Pierre: answered as post due to char limit and lack of syntax highlighting in comments